# MySQL sum results into a table grid format

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL code:

```
select distinct members_main.membership_type,
payment_method,sum(amount_paid) 
from members_main, members_payments
where members_main.contact_id=members_payments.contact_id 
group by members_main.membership_type,payment_method
```

That returns the following:

[image]

I want to be able to return the results in the following table grid format:

[image]

Does anyone know if or how I can do this within MySQL?

Thanks,

John

Comment: `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on data complexity either go with bluefeet's way or if the payment_method amount is dynamic then it sounds like you need a pivot table. Try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have a *pivot* function but you can use a `CASE` expression and an aggregate function to turn the rows into columns:

```
select  m.membership_type,
    sum(case when p.payment_method = 'Cash' then amount_paid else 0 end) Cash,
    sum(case when p.payment_method = 'Credit Card' then amount_paid else 0 end) CreditCard,
    sum(case when p.payment_method = 'Paypal' then amount_paid else 0 end) Paypal
from members_main m
inner join members_payments p
    on m.contact_id=p.contact_id 
group by m.membership_type;
```

If you are going to have an unknown number of `payment_method`'s, then you will want to look at using a prepared statement to generate dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN p.payment_method = ',
      payment_method,
      ' THEN amount_paid else 0 END) AS `',
      payment_method, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM members_payments ;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT m.membership_type, ', @sql, ' 
            from members_main m
            inner join members_payments p
                on m.contact_id=p.contact_id 
            group by m.membership_type');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```